# Reccuring Time Based Workflow in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement where I need to update a custom field(number data-type) with number increasing every hour, I tried using time based workflow but unable to get my head around it. Can someone please help me, I am very new to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this with a Time-based workflow.
Let's assume the field you want to update is called **hour counter**

1. Create the workflow with evaluation criteria - **created, and every time it's edited**
2. Select "formula" rule criteria and in the formula enter `ISCHANGED(hour_counter__c) || ISNEW()`
3. Save the rule and click on **Add Time Trigger**
4. Set it to be executed after 1 hour of Rule Trigger Date
5. In the "Add Workflow Action" section you can add a field update with formula `IF( ISBLANK(hour_counter__c) , 1, hour_counter__c + 1)` (if you're using a defualt value for the field, you don't have to add the ISBLANK check, you can simply use hour_counter__c + 1 in the formula). **NOTE:** Ensure that the **Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change** checkbox on the field update is selected.
6. Hit save, create new record and test the values.

P.S. : I have not done anything like this but logically it seems that it should work.

Comment: Thank you sir, your logic is up to the point. Much appreciated.